# Copy table FROM error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I defined a new datatype, say

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS face_axis ( face INTEGER, normal real[]);
```

where normal should be a vector.

I have already write them on harddisk, like

```
5, 1,0,0,
....
```

Then I want to use

```
COPY face_axis FROM 'face_axis.csv' with csv;
```

but it reports error

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

what's wrong with it? thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The array contents must be enclosed in brackets in all cases
2. Ambiguous use of comma as both the CSV delimiter and delimiter of values inside the array.

You may use a different CSV separator or quote the contents according to CSV rules:

To be loaded with `COPY table FROM file with csv delimiter ';'`

> 1;{1.0,2.0}

To be loaded with `COPY table FROM file with csv`

> 1,"{1.0,2.0}"